Desugaring error when running on React Native Android
I'm building a app for a Pax SmartPOS using the Zoop SmartPOS SDK, it uses Android SDK 23 so I need to use the coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled for it to be able to use the java time Instant.
The problem is that when I enable Desugaring my app doesn't start, it crashes with the following error:

Failed to register native method com.facebook.react.devsupport.CxxInspectorPackagerConnection$WebSocketDelegate.didFailWithError(Ljava/util/OptionalInt;Ljava/lang/String;)V in /data/app/com.zoop-2/base.apk

The full trace can be found here.
I've tried things like downgrading Gradle version but nothing seems to work.
This is my build.gradle (app) file:
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

react {
}

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.zoop"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zoop"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/getzoop/zoop-package-public")
        credentials {
            username = ""    // Seu usuário do GitHub.
            password = "" // Sua PAT do GitHub.
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("br.zoop.pos.plugin:smartpos-pax-a910:1.8.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.9.22")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.6.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10"
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0")

    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4'

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

And my build.gradle (module) file:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"


Add desugarring sdk in you gradle file.
dependencies {
...
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.6'
...
}

compileOptions {

    //enable desugaring library
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}


I already have Desugarring SDK added

Try using the same version as I have used. i.e 1.1.6

The documentation does not suggest to desugar anything. Don't use desugaring, but install and use JDK 17, as required:
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

"Failed to register native method" usually comes from obfuscation and missing -keep rules.

Actually, I need to use desugaring, I don't know why it's not in the docs but is in the example application they provide
And if I try to use the SDK without desugaring it throws an error that Java Time Instant don't exists

Time instant does not exists, because you're using the wrong JDK. And what targeting API level 34, you have to build with JDK 17 anyway. Likely the Gradle version is just as outdated as the dependencies there ...
